# In java8 Collectors.toMap, keyMapper value should come from another constant map's key

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a situation like :

In my project i am using spring boot with spring data.So right now i have to filter my main entity on various fields. Fields and their value are coming in json format in request body in post call like this.

```
{
  "filters": [
    {
      "field": "ownerUiids",
      "terms": "1,2"
    },
    {
      "field": "key",
      "terms": "a"
    },
    {
       and many more
    }
  ],
  "sortBy": "wwww"
}
```

I have a pojo class to convert this json into java.and in that pojo class contain list of fields coming from json.

I converted this list into map of field and its value as key and value like :

```
Map<String,String> filterMap =
            request.getFilters().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Filter::getField,
                    Filter::getTerms));
```

So my problem starts here the name of field in json doesnot match with my column name in db, so while making criteria api the actual column name doesnot appear in query making.

To solve this problem i made constant static map with key as a json field and value is actual column name corresponding to that field like :

```
public static final Map<String, String> myMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(
            new HashMap<String, String>() {{
                put("ownerUiids", "ownerUIID");
                put("key", "keyValue");
            }});
```

So when i am making filterMap i need the key should be value of constant myMap i.e instead of Filter::getField if i can do myMap.getKey(Filter::getField). But right now i am not able to do like this.

```
Map<String,String> filterMap =
                request.getFilters().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(myMap.getKey(Filter::getField),
                        Filter::getTerms));
```

After this thing i have my map of column name and its value which is my current req. and also solve my problem.

Please help me in this sol. or if you have better approach than this then that is also appreciable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use method reference like that. Try this:

```
Map<String,String> filterMap =
       request.getFilters().stream()
              .collect(Collectors.toMap(f -> myMap.get(f.getField()),
                    Filter::getTerms));
```

Answer (score 0):

for the reason create dto class and format raw data

1 : create dto and write converter method in dto class

```
List<Dto> dtos = request.getFilters().stream().map(Dto::convert).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

2 : and now create map

```
Map<String,String> filterMap = dtos.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Dto::getField,Dto::getTerms))
```